# jQuery display all containers where data-index bigger or equal

Tags: jquery

I have a many DIV-Containers with different index. How can i display with jQuery all containers with index bigger or equal data-index="3"? All containers with smaller index should be hidden.

Example

```
<div class="container" data-index="0"></div>
<div class="container" data-index="1"></div>
<div class="container" data-index="2"></div>
<div class="container" data-index="3"></div>
<div class="container" data-index="4"></div>
<div class="container" data-index="5"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) along with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
var target = $('.container').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data("index") >= 3;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this by using [jquery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var divs = $('.container').filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("data-index") >= 3;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div:gt(1)').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-index="0">1</div>
<div class="container" data-index="1">2</div>
<div class="container" data-index="2">3</div>
<div class="container" data-index="3">4</div>
<div class="container" data-index="4">5</div>
<div class="container" data-index="5">6</div>
```

1. use [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each($('.container'),function(){
  var dataIndex = $(this).attr("data-index");
  If(parseInt(dataIndex) <= 2){
  $(this).hide();
  }
  else{
   $(this).show();
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the reverse order  using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
$(".container").filter(function() {
   return $(this).data("index") < 3 
}).css("display","none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-index="0">0</div>
<div class="container" data-index="1">1</div>
<div class="container" data-index="2">2</div>
<div class="container" data-index="3">3</div>
<div class="container" data-index="4">4</div>
<div class="container" data-index="5">5</div>
```